# zend_compile_file hook not working in PHP Extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

**Problem background**

I'm making a PHP 7 extension for learning purpose. In the extension, my end goal is to implement encryption/decryption using OpenSSL (AES_256_CBC). I plan expose a function `encdec7_compile_file` which will compile and given PHP file. Also, in same extension, I wanted to hook `zend_compile_file` to decrypt file in memory, before it is compiled/executed.

**What I did till now?**

I make simple extension code, to test above two function are working fine. In `encdec7_compile_file`, I'm simply printing parameters and generating warning, it is working fine.

In zend_compile_file, I'm trying to print/log to confirm function is getting called but there is no log so I believe function is not getting called. My code

**encdec7.c**

```
/* encdec7 extension for PHP 7 */

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "php_encdec7.h"

static zend_op_array *compile_binary_file(zend_file_handle *, int TSRMLS_DC);

/* For compatibility with older PHP versions */
#ifndef ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_NONE
#define ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_NONE() \
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(0, 0) \
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END()
#endif

// static void php_encdec_init_globals(zend_encdec_globals *encdec_globals)
// {
//  encdec_globals->initialized = 0;
// }
// ENCDECG(initialized) = 1;

PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(encdec7)
{
    // ZEND_INIT_MODULE_GLOBALS(encdec7, php_encdec_init_globals, NULL);
    // REGISTER_INI_ENTRIES();

    // if (!ENCDECG(initialized)) {
        orig_compile_file = zend_compile_file;
        zend_compile_file = compile_binary_file;
        // ENCDECG(initialized) = 1;
    // }

    REGISTER_STRING_CONSTANT("ENCDEC_EXT_VERSION", PHP_ENCDEC7_VERSION, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(encdec7)
{
    // if (ENCDECG(initialized)) {
        zend_compile_file = orig_compile_file;
    // }
    // UNREGISTER_INI_ENTRIES();

    // ENCDECG(initialized) = 0;
    return SUCCESS;
}

/* {{{ string encdec7_compile_file( [ string $var ] )
 */
PHP_FUNCTION(encdec7_compile_file)
{
    // End PHP user will call this function with two parameters ($src, $target)
    // Name and length of source and target
    char *filename;
    size_t filename_len;
    char *effective_path = NULL;
    size_t effective_path_len;

    // Get the parameters
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(2, 2)
        Z_PARAM_STRING(filename, filename_len)
        Z_PARAM_STRING(effective_path, effective_path_len)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    encdec_warning("Checking how warning displays - 3\n");

    php_printf("src = %s and target = %s\r\n", filename, effective_path);
}
/* }}}*/

/* {{{ PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION
 */
PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(encdec7)
{
#if defined(ZTS) && defined(COMPILE_DL_ENCDEC7)
    ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE();
#endif

    return SUCCESS;
}
/* }}} */

/* {{{ PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION
 */
PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(encdec7)
{
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_header(2, "encdec7 support", "enabled");
    php_info_print_table_end();
}
/* }}} */

/* {{{ encdec7_functions[]
 */
static const zend_function_entry encdec7_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(encdec7_compile_file, NULL)
    PHP_FE_END
};
/* }}} */

/* {{{ encdec7_module_entry
 */
zend_module_entry encdec7_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "encdec7",                  /* Extension name */
    encdec7_functions,          /* zend_function_entry */
    NULL,                           /* PHP_MINIT - Module initialization */
    NULL,                           /* PHP_MSHUTDOWN - Module shutdown */
    PHP_RINIT(encdec7),         /* PHP_RINIT - Request initialization */
    NULL,                           /* PHP_RSHUTDOWN - Request shutdown */
    PHP_MINFO(encdec7),         /* PHP_MINFO - Module info */
    PHP_ENCDEC7_VERSION,        /* Version */
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};
/* }}} */

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_ENCDEC7
# ifdef ZTS
ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_DEFINE()
# endif
ZEND_GET_MODULE(encdec7)
#endif

static zend_op_array* compile_binary_file(zend_file_handle* h, int type TSRMLS_DC) {
    zend_file_handle *orig_file_handle = h;

    encdec_warning("Warning from compile_binary_file");
    php_printf("Printed from compile_binary_file");

    FILE *fptr;

    char c[] = "Printed from compile_binary_file in /home/kapil/program.txt";
    fptr = fopen("/home/kapil/program.txt", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fptr, "%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);

    // Comment below to knowingly add error so that it break, but not breaking.
    // return orig_compile_file(orig_file_handle, type TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

**php_encdec7.h**

```
/* encdec7 extension for PHP */

#ifndef PHP_ENCDEC7_H
# define PHP_ENCDEC7_H

#define encdec_error(format...)   php_error(E_ERROR, format)
#define encdec_warning(format...) php_error(E_WARNING, format)

extern zend_module_entry encdec7_module_entry;
# define phpext_encdec7_ptr &encdec7_module_entry

# define PHP_ENCDEC7_VERSION "0.1.0"

ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS(encdec)
    zend_bool initialized;
ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS(encdec)

zend_op_array *(*orig_compile_file)(zend_file_handle *, int TSRMLS_DC);

# if defined(ZTS) && defined(COMPILE_DL_ENCDEC7)
ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_EXTERN()
# endif

// #ifdef ZTS
// #define ENCDECG(v) TSRMG(encdec_globals_id, zend_encdec_globals *, v)
// #else
// #define ENCDECG(v) (encdec_globals->v)
// #endif

#endif  /* PHP_ENCDEC7_H */
```

**Testing**

I'm trying to test it with simple PHP files

**test.php**

```php
<?php

include_once("test2.php");

echo "Calling encdec7_compile_file<br/>" . PHP_EOL;

encdec7_compile_file("Kapil", "Sharma");
```

**test2.php**

```php
<?php

echo "Printed from test2";
```

**Problem**

Running `php test.php` or in browser, generate following output:

```
Printed from test2Calling encdec7_compile_file

Warning: Checking how warning displays - 3 in /var/www/html/test.php on line 7
src = Kapil and target = Sharma
```

However, code in `compile_binary_file` is not executed as there is no output in console/web + `program.txt` is blank. Also tried commenting last line but there is no error.

Could someone suggest what mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, we defined MINIT and MSHUTDOWN but didn't tell Zend engine about it. Problem will be fixed with this

```
zend_module_entry encdec7_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "encdec7",                  /* Extension name */
    encdec7_functions,          /* zend_function_entry */
    PHP_MINIT(encdec7),         /* PHP_MINIT - Module initialization */
    PHP_MSHUTDOWN(encdec7),     /* PHP_MSHUTDOWN - Module shutdown */
    PHP_RINIT(encdec7),         /* PHP_RINIT - Request initialization */
    NULL,                           /* PHP_RSHUTDOWN - Request shutdown */
    PHP_MINFO(encdec7),         /* PHP_MINFO - Module info */
    PHP_ENCDEC7_VERSION,        /* Version */
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};
```

We added `PHP_MINIT(encdec7)` and `PHP_MSHUTDOWN(encdec7)` instead of `NULL` as 4th and 5th parameter respectively in `zend_module_entry`.